# Google Pie Chart pointing line between legend and pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart, google-pie-chart

I would like to add a line to connect the pie chart to the label so the user can see what is the legend for the particular part of pie chart.
these are the codes i use to generate my piechart

```
function drawVisualizationIamIn(dataValues) {
    console.log(dataValues)
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');
    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]);
    }
    new google.visualization.PieChart(
        document.getElementById('visualizationIamIn')
    ).draw(data, {
        title: "Members by Industry Type",
        sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#e0e7eb'
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.
below is the chart i generate with codes above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following option...

```
{
  legend: {
    position: 'labeled'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I couldn't believe I missed this when I was reading the documentation for google charts. Thank you, mate.